# Convert number in Julian format 'yyyyddd' to Date

Tags: date, teradata, julian-date

How do I convert a numeric in Julian format 'yyyyddd' to a proper Date value in Teradata?
For example from '2014001' to '2014-01-01'.

Please provide two examples, first when '2014001' is a numeric and second when it is a character.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some trial-and-error I've found the answer.

If the data is character, then:

```
Cast(<Column Name> As Date Format ‘yyyyddd’)
```

If the data is numeric, then:

```
Cast(Cast(<Column Name> As Char(7)) As Date Format ‘yyyyddd’)
```